# Fit from lm in R does not equal group means?

Tags: regression, r, lm

I define `data` such that:

- The outcome variable `performance` is a number between 0 and 1
- `high_school` is either private or municipal
- `coarse_educ` is either A or B

I estimate:

```
> incorrect_reg <- lm(performance ~ high_school + coarse_educ, data = data)
> coef(incorrect_reg)
       (Intercept) high_schoolprivate       coarse_educB 
         0.5626956         -0.2123540          0.2441017
```

Meanwhile:

```
> data[high_school == "municipal" & coarse_educ == "A", mean(performance)]
[1] 0.5447622
```

Why does the intercept not match this mean I calculate manually? The fitted values should be the means of the corresponding groups, or am I very confused? I understand there can be some numerical issues but the difference seems quite large... Similarly when I compare the model fit with other group means, the results don't match:

```
> sum(coef(incorrect_reg))
[1] 0.5944433
> data[high_school == "private" & coarse_educ == "B", mean(performance)]
[1] 0.5765099
```

Full MRE below. If this seems like a strange MRE, the point of doing this in the first place was to do something else (illustrate what can happen if we specify our control variables incorrectly).

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

# Define schools:
data <- data.table(high_school = c(rep("municipal", 50), rep("private", 50)))

# Define coarse university educations A and B:
data[, coarse_educ := c(rep("A", 25), rep("B", 25)), high_school]

# Define easy and hard subcategories of A and B:
data[high_school == "municipal" & coarse_educ == "A", sub_difficulty := c(rep("Easy", 20), rep("Hard", 5))]
data[high_school == "municipal" & coarse_educ == "B", sub_difficulty := c(rep("Easy", 20), rep("Hard", 5))]

# Assume most private high schools students study hard subcategories:
data[high_school == "private" & coarse_educ == "A", sub_difficulty := c(rep("Easy", 5), rep("Hard", 20))]
data[high_school == "private" & coarse_educ == "B", sub_difficulty := c(rep("Easy", 5), rep("Hard", 20))]

# Assume there is no variation between private and municipal students
# Therefore, assign outcomes (% passed credits) based on only coarse_educ and sub_difficulty:

data[coarse_educ == "A" & sub_difficulty == "Easy", performance := 0.6 + runif(25, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)]
data[coarse_educ == "A" & sub_difficulty == "Hard", performance := 0.3 + runif(25, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)]

data[coarse_educ == "B" & sub_difficulty == "Easy", performance := 0.9 + runif(25, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)]
data[coarse_educ == "B" & sub_difficulty == "Hard", performance := 0.5 + runif(25, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)]

# Regression controlling incorrectly:
incorrect_reg <- lm(performance ~ high_school + coarse_educ, data = data)
coef(incorrect_reg)

# Not equal to intercept:
data[high_school == "municipal" & coarse_educ == "A", mean(performance)]

# Not equal to each other:
sum(coef(incorrect_reg))
data[high_school == "private" & coarse_educ == "B", mean(performance)]
```

Comment: "The fitted values should be the means of the corresponding groups" - this is not quite correct. Try fitting `performance ~ high_school * coarse_edu`, compare the results, then think about why they are different.

Comment: Ah, I need the interaction terms, and now it all works out... Need to sleep and think about this, I should of course know this... Thanks!